# AsciiDoc -> Docbook not showing images

Tags: image, docbook, asciidoc

I am having some trouble with an AsciiDoc document. It uses an image, but the image is only shown in the HTML version, but not in the PDF version.

I have this short document:

```
Test book
=========
Robert Larsen
:doctype: book

Test chapter
------------
image:test_image.jpg[Test image]
```

This looks fine in HTML. But when I convert first to Docbook and then to PDF (using db2pdf), then only the alternative text is shown.

The Docbook version is:

```
<book lang="en">
<bookinfo>
    <title>Test book</title>
    <author>
        <firstname>Robert</firstname>
        <surname>Larsen</surname>
    </author>
    <authorinitials>RL</authorinitials>
</bookinfo>
<chapter id="_test_chapter">
<title>Test chapter</title>
<simpara><inlinemediaobject>
  <imageobject>
  <imagedata fileref="test_image.jpg"/>
  </imageobject>
  <textobject><phrase>Test image</phrase></textobject>
</inlinemediaobject></simpara>
</chapter>
</book>
```

I have tried other image formats as well, so that is not it.
I use Ubuntu 12.10

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain why the image is missing (perphaps there is something wrong with the processing of `inlinemediaobject`). In any case, **db2pdf** is part of an old toolchain (based on DSSSL stylesheets) that is hardly maintained anymore.

It will work if you use the more modern DocBook-XSL stylesheets together with FOP. See this Ubuntu documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DocBook#DocBook_to_PDF.